# How to interpolate String in Groovy?

Tags: groovy

I have multiple variables of list types. I have another list type variable which holds the all variables name as values.

```
def A = ['abc','def','ghi']
def B = ['123','456','789']
def C = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']

def masterList = ['A','B','C']

masterList.each {

    println "${${it}}"

}
```

I want output as

'abc','def','ghi'

'123','456','789'

'ABC','DEF','GHI'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

if it's a script then this will work:

```
A = ['abc','def','ghi']
B = ['123','456','789']
C = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']

def masterList = ['A','B','C']

masterList.each {
    println this."$it"
}
```

note that there is no `def` in front of `A,B,C`

Answer (score 1):

You can't reference dynamically those variables, if they're local-scoped.

Solution 1: use a map for your lists:

```
def map = ['A': ['abc','def','ghi'],
           'B': ['123','456','789']
           'C': ['ABC','DEF','GHI']]
```

And then

```
masterList.each {println map[it]}
```

Solution 2: make `A`, `B`, and `C` instance variables of the current class (if they are not already), after which you can read those properties dynamically using the bracket notation:

```
masterList.each {println this[it]}
```

Answer (score 0):

If it would be in a `class`:

```
class Foo {
    def A = ['abc','def','ghi']
    def B = ['123','456','789']
    def C = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']
}

Foo foo = new Foo()
def masterList = ['A','B','C']
masterList.each {
    println foo[it]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Though this will depend on your use case, the following works just fine...  as long as your variables are class-level variables...

```
class MyClass {
  def A = ['abc','def','ghi']
  def B = ['123','456','789']
  def C = ['ABC','DEF','GHI']

  def test(String role, String group) {
    def masterList = ['A','B','C']
    masterList.each { it ->
      println(" ${it} = ${this[it]}")
    }
  }
}
```

Results:

```
A = [abc, def, ghi]
B = [123, 456, 789]
C = [ABC, DEF, GHI]
```